# How can i make a custom action execute something on specific intervals

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, skaction

So Whenever i run this action, it prints hello world rapidly for 3 seconds (which is what i want), but it prints it too fast. What i cant figure out is how to print "hello world" on certain intervals within the duration of the action (e.g 1 second intervals). I tried using the sleep function, but it didnt work

```
let waitAndPrint = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(3) {
            _, _ in
    print("hello world")    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but maybe something like this would work

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) //<-where 3 is the number of seconds over which you want this event to occur. 
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(printHelloWorld:) withObject:self afterDelay:i];
}

-(void) printHelloWorld:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"hello world")
}
```

It's in obj c but you get the idea

**EDIT**

Per Whirlwind's recommendations, I've changed `afterDelay:1` to `afterDelay:i`. I also fixed the selector syntax error by adding the colon after `printHelloWorld`.

Comment: I know you said its untested, but you have an error. If you use afterDelay:1 the code will print message three times after one second. You probably meant to use afterDelay: i Also, another problem with this approach is that code will continue with executing even if view or scene is paused.

Comment: wouldn't it just loop through the command to print after 1 second three times? So once every second three times?

Comment: Nope. Try it for yourself. Because you call performSelector inside for loop which is executed almost instantaneously(and every time delay is set to 1 second).

Comment: It will work if you use afterDelay: i, and if you change @selector(printHelloWorld) into @selector(printHelloWorld:) because there is a paramter in printHelloWord method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you are trying to achieve with actions:

```
let block = SKAction.runBlock{
    println("hello world")
}

scene.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence([block, SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)]), count: 3))
```